# Failed to resolve: exifinterface

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, picasso

When I upgrade picasso from 2.5.2 to 2.71828 and do a gradle sync I see a a
exifinterface error:

Error:

```
Failed to resolve: exifinterface
```

Replaced

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Comment: Solved this yet?

Comment: It looks like a problem with my build system. Our internal artifactory does not get populated or is not able bring the exifinterface 2.7.1 jar.

Answer (score 9):

Picasso have dependencies to `exifinterface` so you must add this to your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
```

If you use **androidX**, add this your `dependencies`

```
implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 3):

Official Solution: 
https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1913

adding `implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'`

Answer (score 1):

i use androidX and below dependency solved my problem :

```
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.1.0-alpha01'
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using the support libraries you should be using a
>   resolution strategy to force them all to the same version.

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        details.useVersion versions.supportLibrary
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Add the [**`ExifInterface Support Library`**](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html) to your project with the following dependency:

```
implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem by adding for androidx:

```
  implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0
```