# Exception: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface;

Tags: android-jetpack, android-exifinterface

First, I am aware of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188614/failed-to-resolve-exifinterface). My situation is different and odd.

An app Foo does not directly use ExifInterface at all. It depends on libraryFoo which is included as an AAR package. libraryFoo uses ExifInterface in a fragment.

When app Foo uses the fragment and the fragment calls a method that uses ExifInterface as follows:

```
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(fileDescriptor);
exifInterface.setGpsInfo(location);
exifInterface.saveAttributes();
```

the app crashes:

```
Failed resolution of: Landroidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface;
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface;
```

Adding the following to the build.gradle of the app solves the problem:

```
implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.3'
```

This is odd. To make this even odder, the app used to work fine without this implementation line.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

You can see that I am not seeking a solution to a problem, but an understanding of this behavior.